# use filename ref instead of path(string) while opening an Excel in Windows c#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, ref

I would need to pass the file name ref instead of giving string (full path) while opening or saving Excel in C#. Below is a code snippet

```
object fileName = (string)e.Argument;

object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

if (fileName.ToString().EndsWith("xlsx"))
{
    Excel.Workbook wb;
    object oMissing1 = Type.Missing;
    var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    wb = app.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\273714\Desktop\ProoferReport1.xlsx", 
                            oMissing1, oMissing1, oMissing1, oMissing1, 
                            oMissing1, oMissing1, oMissing1, oMissing1, 
                            oMissing1, oMissing1, oMissing1, oMissing1, 
                            oMissing1, oMissing1);
    wb.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\273714\Desktop\Proofer Report2.xls", 
                            Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8, Type.Missing, 
                            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                            Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, 
                            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    app.Quit();
    app.Quit();
}
```

In case of a word document i can just open it like

```
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref oMissing,
               ref readOnly, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
               ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
               ref oMissing, ref isVisible, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
               ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

I need the same way of using the file name in Excel too. Any help will be grateful.

Comment: Not sure exactly what your question means. You want to use pass `filename.xlsx` instead of `C:\filename.xlsx`?

Comment: i wanna pass the object filename there instead of string as i browse the file and open that. the file name keeps changing.i dont want to hardcode it

Comment: you have full path to file in `fileName` object?

Comment: So just use a file open dialog, get the user to select the file, check it is the correct file, then show a save as dialog for the user to save it again.....

Comment: I'm confused.. why can't you just use the `fileName` variable? (or just `File.Copy`)

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you just want to pass the variable FileName instead of passing a constant string "c:\aFilename.xlsx"?

To do that replace `object filename` with `string filename` and then type `ref filename` instead of `ref @"c:\aFilename.xlsx"`.

Also be aware of the `System.IO.FileInfo` class - instead of doing `fileName.ToString().EndsWith("xlsx")` you could do `Path.GetExtension(filename).Equals("xlsx",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` to take advantage of the built in functions for finding file extensions (this also avoids (for example) filename.abcxlsx from passing the test).

Comment: `Path.GetExtension(fileName)` is a better alternative (Although I don't know what the question really is to say if this answers the question)

Comment: Good point @Sayse - I'd used `System.IO.FileInfo` since originally I'd stuck the filename in there, then realised since it's being passed as a ref it would be better to store it in a string variable so a value could be returned, but stopped thinking at that point.  Updating answer now.  Thanks.